# jQuery addOption and selectOptions

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

I have to deal with some old Javascript code that is throwing an error at **addOption** and **selectOptions**

> Error: Object has no method **selectOptions**

Can someone explain me why is it not working? I am using jQuery 1.3

```
$("some_id").addOption(nodeId, nodeName); // add to list
$("some_id").selectOptions(/^~~/i, true); // clear selection
```

I solved the addOption line by this

```
$("some_id")[0].options.add( new Option(nodeName,nodeId));
```

but I'm still stuck with **selectOptions** error.

**UPDATE**
just found out the application is also using **Dojo**. Could that be the problem? Are these methods Dojo specific?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps `first_option = $('some_id')[0].options[0].value;
$('some_id').val(first_option);`

Comment: Or even `$('select').val('')`

Comment: have you checked if there's an selectOption function declaration in your code before? The error says that the function doesn't exist an as far as I know there is no native jQuery selectOptions function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found whats wrong with it.
These methods come from a **[jquery plugin](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/select/)** by TexoTela.
*Why would someone do that just for select boxes?? Beats me*

> Thanks everybody for the responses. They taught me something indeed.

Answer (score 2):

use [Jquery Append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add options like this

```
$("yourid/class here").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", youroption-value).text(youroption-text));
```

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that approach, but I need to know what exactly the second line is doing. It's clearing what?

Comment: cant say, never used that approach to clear select list options, i always used .empty() or .remove()

Comment: Thanks anyway, I think this has to do with Dojo

Answer (score 1):

try this, you can write your own methods:

```
$.fn.addOption = function(optText, optValue){
    var option = new Option(optText, optValue);
    return this.append(option);
};

$.fn.selectOption = function(toSelect){
 var $option = this.find("option[value='"+toSelect+"']");    
    if($option.length > 0){  
        //if option with the value passed on found then select it      
        $option.prop("selected","selected");
    }else{
        alert("option not found");
    }
};

var $select = $("#selectOption");
$select.addOption("Dummy1",2);
$select.addOption("Dummy2",3);

$select.selectOption(231);
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/maverickosama92/rGzPS/1/